# How I can make the text file to json file?

Tags: text-processing, json

I have text file containing something like the following:

```
google.com,father@google.com,json@google.com
latter.com,john@latter.com
```

I am trying to convert this text to Json format like this:

```
{
"domain": "google.com",
"emails":[{"email":"father@google.com","First":"xyz","Last":"pqr"},{"email":"json@google.com","First":"xyz","Last":"pqr"}]

}
{
"domain": "latter.com",
"emails":[{"email":"john@latter.com","First":"xyz","Last":"pqr"}]
}
```

Is it possible to make such text to something in this sort of JSON format? Please let me know.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813863/how-to-convert-text-file-to-json-data-in-perl

Comment: @Rinzwind No this is not solving the problem I tried it previously.

Comment: This question belongs in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Nisheet Is it not possible to do with the help of Ubuntu to achieve this particular problem?

Comment: @JafferWilson, this is a generic programming query not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: @JafferWilson we are not suppose to provide code snippets for you. This could be homework... and then you'd be cheating ;-) Plus as nisheet says: using Ubuntu does not make coding questions a subject on AU. SO is for that.

Comment: @Rinzwind :P it is not a homework for me. Actually, I was stuck in formatting using ubuntu. I was forcebly asked to use Ubuntu instead of my general system. Hence, I thought to ask this query here. But this was nice conversation with you... :)

Comment: OK, first of all, your input and output don't align. Where in the heck does "First" and "Last" come from ?  It's not in the input file you've provided

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty perl:

```
perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
    print encode_json({
        domain => shift @F, 
        emails => [map {{email => $_, First=>"xyz", Last=>"pqr"}} @F]
    })
' file
```

Or ugly ugly awk

```
awk -F, '{
    printf "{\"domain\":\"%s\",\"emails\":[", $1
    sep=""
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s{\"email\":\"%s\",\"First\":\"xyz\",\"Last\":\"pqr\"}", sep, $i
        sep=","
    }
    print "]}"
}' file
```

Comment: Your answer is faster. But the Perl is giving the output in reverse order. Means. Emails first and then domain in the out JSON. The another solution is giving error: `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="/home/aims/Desktop/FinalOut1" FNR=186843 NR=186843
` Can you help me with this. I am trying to edit the perl example.

Comment: It's a JSON object. The order of the keys does not matter. The process you're feeding the data to, does it rely on the keys being in a certain order?

Answer (score 1):

@Jaffer Wilson
Here is a quick and dirty bash script that might help you

```bsh
function to_json() {
echo -en '{\n"domain":"'"$1"'",\n"emails":['
shift
EC=0
for EMAIL in "$@"
do
    echo -n '{"email":"'"$EMAIL"'","First":"xyz","Last":"pqr"}'
    EC=`expr "$EC" + 1`
    if [ "$EC" -ne "$#" ]; then
        echo -n ","
    fi
done
echo -e "]\n},"
}

while read LINE
do
    PARAMS=$(echo "$LINE" | tr "," " ")
    to_json "$PARAMS"
done
```

I saved it as convert_to_json.sh and suppose data.txt is where the text is run it as

```
$ chmod +x convert_to_json.sh
$ ./convert_to_json.sh < data.txt
```

Comment: The bash is working fine. But I wonder, is there a faster way to achieve the output?

Comment: Your code is very fragile. Please read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667). Try pasting your code into http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @glenn jackman, Thanks a lot for your suggestions! I updated my code.